# clips use string to make a compare condition

Tags: string, syntax, compare, conditional-statements, clips

I'm very very new to Clips expert system
I'm looking for what is a syntax to use for compare a text from previous rules

like this

```
(defrule GetGender
(declare (salience 100))
(printout t "What's your gender ? (Male/Female): ")
(bind ?response (read))
(assert (Gender (gender ?response))))
```

and when I get answer from above like "Male" I want the rule below active.

```
(defrule GetShirt
(declare (salience 99))
(Gender (gender ?l))
(test (= ?l Male))
=>
(printout t "What's your shirt color ? (Blue/Black): ")
(bind ?response (read))
(assert (Shirt (shirt ?response))))
```

But seem (test and =) is not a syntax for string compare, and my English is not good enough, I don't even know about what "?l" in the code means

could somebody help me to fix this out please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use = for comparing numbers and eq for comparing values of any type. In your GetShirt rule, the token ?l is a variable that is bound to the value of the gender slot so that it can be used in the expression (= ?l Male). When making simple comparisons to constants, it's not necessary to use the test conditional element. You can simply use the constant within the pattern:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate response
   (slot attribute)
   (slot value))
CLIPS> 
(defrule GetGender
   =>
   (printout t "What's your gender ? (Male/Female): ")
   (bind ?response (read))
   (assert (response (attribute gender) (value ?response))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule GetShirt
   (response (attribute gender) (value Male))
   =>
   (printout t "What's your shirt color ? (Blue/Black): ")
   (bind ?response (read))
   (assert (response (attribute shirt) (value ?response))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
What's your gender ? (Male/Female): Male
What's your shirt color ? (Blue/Black): Blue
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Hi, Gary Riley, Thank you so much for your example, I've done few minutes ago with you and @noxdafox help, I'm appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is for comparing numbers.

For strings, you need to use the `eq` function.

```
In [1]: (eq "foo" "bar")
FALSE
In [2]: (eq "foo" "foo")
TRUE
```

Comment: Hi noxdafox thank you for your answer, could you please show me how to use this in my code, I'm not quite understand, what is "foo" and "bar" ?